# How to continue working on my LaTeX project from pc (Window 10, TeXstudio, MiKTeX) to Android phone (VerbTeX)?

Tags: online, android

I need to work anytime, anywhere using [VerbTeX](https://www.verbosus.com/android-latex-editor.html) (newly installed) on my Android phone from my existing LaTeX project in my laptop. How to do that?

Comment: For the uninitiated: What is Verbtex?

Comment: Have you tried an online service? You can either work completely online with (e.g.) [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) or offline, but with the file sync-ed in the ether  -- see (e.g.) [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/).  Many dozens of other options exist.

Comment: @Mico: A latex - on-the-fly (i.e. compilation on a server) app... it works, however, it's a little bit tedious to type latex on the tablet/phone

Comment: @Mico VerbTeX is this: https://www.verbosus.com/, they have also an app for your smartphone or tablet.

Comment: As I can work offline on my PC, can I do the same on my android phone off line? Perhaps can I transfer all necessary files from PC to the local storage SD card in VerbTex, how n will it works? Thx.

Comment: @CaseyYeow: As far as I know `VerbTeX` needs some internet connection, so 'offline' is only a dream then...

Comment: Look at Tex Writer https://apps.texwriter.net

Comment: I have internet connection with no data limit, but I prefer not to work online like Overleaf. That is, no issue with internet connection, but I want all my working files  localize within my phone. Is it possible with VerbTex? If not, is texwriter in android the only best option, I saw 3.7 star rating only.

Comment: @CaseyYeow AFAIK only TexWriter and LaTeX Editor https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.talos.latexeditor allow to compile offline on Android devices.

Comment: how do you migrate Latex files from PC to these android phone latex apps? Thx.

Comment: More detail: I have a existing Latex project (files) in PC. I would like to transfer or copy these files into a android phone Latex apps like VerbTex or Latex Editor and continue working on the same project on phone.

Comment: Within TexWriter you could use DropBox, but in any case a USB cable should work.